keras package in R requires tensorflow, throws error
I have been trying to launch the keras package in R:
library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", 
                  python = virtualenv_starter())
library(keras)
install_keras(envname = "r-reticulate")

This code, however, throws an error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.15.* (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.15.*
Error: Error installing package(s): "'tensorflow==2.15.*'", "tensorflow-hub", "tensorflow-datasets", "scipy", "requests", "Pillow", "h5py", "pandas", "pydot"

I have tried various ways to fix it.

Following these instructions, I have tried to install with Homebrew, but after hours of waiting had to quit the operation.
Installing from link as described here. This seems to have added a wrong version of Tensorflow to my pythonenv, because install_keras() keeps throwing error.
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.15 returns No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.15.

I have not worked with virtualenv before, and am completely at a loss.  I guess a solution might be to downgrade Python from 3.12, but not sure how to proceed correctly. My Session info:
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.7.10

Updating MacOS to Sonoma and updating keras to keras3 did the trick.
